# Returning multiple values in a single cell that match criteria

Tags: excel

I am trying to find a function that will help me do the following (without using VBA). So suppose i have the following data:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Ql2Z7yR.jpg]

**I need it to be the following format:**

[image: http://i.imgur.com/OkRsbKE.jpg]

Basically, I need to get all the associated sku's (column F) from the parent_sku (column E) into column G comma delimited.

Comment: What did the edit do, I see no links/images.  Are there multiple SKUs within one cell?  or does parent_sku in E1 have one associated_sku in F1?  Are you plucking multiple skus from one cell to be put back into a cell in column G?

Comment: Trevor, do you see the images now?

Comment: Without VBA? You'd be using a lot of `&` statements, like in @klma7lwa proposed solution.  This sort of thing is generally done with VBA.  For example: http://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/860240-concatall-udf-by-tigeravatar.html

Comment: Are the sku's always in the form of a set of 5 items i.e. p-Small, p-Medium, p-Large, p-XL, p-XL where p is the parent sku? Is the order (Small, Medium, Large,... ) always the same? Do the "child" sku's always occur in the rows immediately preceding a row where the entries in the parent_sku and sku columns are the same? The answers to these questions determine how simple or difficult your problem is to solve.

Comment: The sub-sku's vary. Thank you for your replies but I actually found a solution! http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/12/20/excel-udf-lookup-and-return-multiple-values-concatenated-into-one-cell/

Answer (score 1):

Excel's native worksheet formulas do not handle concatenating an unknown number of strings  together and compensating for the maximum number possible can get messy. A User Defined Function¹ (aka UDF) takes advantage of VBA's ability to process loops through a large number of rows while making numerical or string comparisons and concatenations.

I had a hard time understanding your data; it seems you are arbitrarily swapping out 506 for 541468 and only implied that the **sku** data was to have the same replacements made by the screenshots you provided. For a more universal solution, I will just consider E13:F13 to be 506 and not 541468.

**[build_SKU_List UDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtfji.png)**¹

```
Function build_SKU_List(sku As Variant, parent_sku As Range, skus As Range, _
                        Optional delim As String = ", ")
    Dim str As String, rw As Long

    With skus.Parent
        Set skus = .Cells(parent_sku.Rows(1).Row, skus.Column). _
                      Resize(parent_sku.Rows.Count, skus.Columns.Count)
    End With

    For rw = Application.Match(sku, parent_sku, 0) _
          To Application.Match(sku, parent_sku) - 1
        str = str & skus(rw) & delim
    Next rw

    build_SKU_List = Left(str, Len(str) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

In your sample data's G2 as,

```
=IF(E2=F2, build_SKU_List(E2,E:E,F:F ), "")
```

Override the default *<comma><space>* delimiter if desired. Results should be similar to the following.

[image: build_SKU_List]
                       <sup>build_SKU_List applied to column G:G</sup>

---

¹ <sub>A User Defined Function (aka UDF) is placed into a standard module code sheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to **Insert ► Module** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the function code into the new module code sheet titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet(s).</sub>

Comment: This is probably going to be the best bet for tackling this issue.  Now, if the sku data range is going to remain mostly static, you can write concatenate function with a ton of internal if statements to check every cell, but honestly the VBA route is the best choice here in terms of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your request well 
But you can try the next

> =E7&"-Small,"&E7&"-Medium,"&E7&"-large,"&E7&"-XL,"&E7&"-2XL"

Comment: So basically I have column E with let's say 500 parent sku's and column F with 1500 sub-sku's. I need in column G, a concatenate of all sub-sku's that are associated with the parent sku (column E)

Answer (score 0):

Credit:
http://www.get-digital-help.com/2010/12/20/excel-udf-lookup-and-return-multiple-values-concatenated-into-one-cell/

Basically, it works like a VLOOKUP only it concatenate's every value in one cell associated with your lookup value.